# asp.net MVC: reroute to action in custom action attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i'm trying to create an attribute that i can set on my controllers action in which i can check if a user in some kind of role.
I know with standard asp.net authentication this is already possible, but i'm not using that.

So what i want to accomplish is this:

```
[Role("Admin", "SuperUser")]
public ActionResult SafeCourse()
```

I've constructed this:

```
public class AdminAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
```

Ans now..... i want to redirect the user to some controller/action or if that isn't possible to some view when he / she is not in the right role.
But i'm not in my usual context (= controller) and i'm somewhat lost :)

Michel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make your action filter implement `IAuthorizationFilter` it will execute before other types ... then in `OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)` set the result.

Something like

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/Controller/ActionYouWantToDirectTo");
```

Kindness,

Dan

Answer (score 0):

### The proper/correct way of doing this

Asp.net MVC has extensibility point exactly for your needs. You should be writing a **custom action method selector attribute** that would actually select the correct action method based on the definition in the attribute.

```
public class RoleAttribute: ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
{
    ...
}
```

Check [this blog post](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2010/12/using-custom-action-method-selector.html) that talks about action method selectors. One of the good extensibility points in Asp.net MVC yet not many developers know about it.